# Prevent moire pattern in pixi.js

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, pixi.js

I'm trying to create a zoomable canvas with rectangles arranged in a grid using pixi.js. Everything works smoothly except that the grid creates heavy moire effects. My knowledge about pixijs and webgl is only very superficial but I'm suspecting that something with the antialiasing is not working as I expect it to. I'm drawing the rectangles using a 2048x2048px texture I create beforehand in separate canvas. I make it that big so I do this so I can zoom in all the way while still having a sharp rectangle. I also tried using `app.renderer.generateTexture(graphics)` but got a similar result.

The black rectangles are drawn using pixi.js and the red ones are drawn using SVG as a reference. There is still moire occurring in the SVG as well but it is much less. Any ideas how I can get closer to what the SVG version looks like? You can find a a working version [here](http://flavio.is/moire-test/).

[image: pixi.js rectangles on the left in black, svg rectangles as reference in red to the right]

Here's the relevant code I use to setup the pixi.js application:

```
// PIXI SETUP

const app = new Application({
  view: canvasRef,
  width,
  height,
  transparent: true,
  antialias: false,
  autoDensity: true,
  resolution: devicePixelRatio,
  resizeTo: window
});

const particleContainer = new ParticleContainer(2500, {
  scale: true,
  position: true,
  rotation: true,
  uvs: true,
  alpha: true
});

app.stage.addChild(particleContainer);

// TEXTURE

const size = 2048;
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = size;
canvas.height = size;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, size, size);
ctx.fill();
const texture = PIXI.Texture.from(canvas);

// RECTANGLE GRID

const size = 10;
for(let i=0; i<2500; i++) {
  const particle = Sprite.from(texture);
  particle.x = i % 50 * size * 1.5;
  particle.y = Math.floor(i / 50) * size * 1.5;
  particle.anchor.set(0);
  particle.width = size;
  particle.height = size;
  parent.addChild(particle);
}
```

Comment: Try generating mip maps for the big texture: https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.html#.MIPMAP_MODES

Answer (score 4):

### Don't render sub pixel detail.

The best way to maintain a grid while avoiding artifacts is to not render grid steps below the resolution of the canvas. Eg if you have zoomed out by 100 then do not draw grids less than 100 pixels.

As this can result in grid steps popping in and out you can fade grids in and out depending on the zoom level.

The example shows one way to do this. It still has some artifacts, these are hard to avoid, but this eliminates the horrid moire patterns you get when you render all the detail at every zoom level.

The grid is defined as 2D repeating patterns to reduce rendering overhead.

Also I find grid lines more problematic than grid squares (Demo has both)

This is very basic and can be adapted to any type of grid layout.

```js
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const size = 138;
const grids = createPatterns(size, 4, "#222", "#EEE", "#69B", "#246");
var zoom = 1;
var zoomTarget = 16;
var zoomC = 0;
var gridType = 0;
var origin = {x: ctx.canvas.width / 2, y: ctx.canvas.height / 2};
const scales = [0,0,0];

function createPatterns(size, lineWidth, color1, color2, color3, color4){
    function grid(col1, col2) {
        ctx.fillStyle = col1;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, size, size);
        ctx.fillStyle = col2;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, size, lineWidth);
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, lineWidth, size);
    }
    function grid2(col1, col2) {
        ctx.fillStyle = col1;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, size, size);
        ctx.fillStyle = col2;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, size / 2, size / 2);
        ctx.fillRect( size / 2, size / 2, size / 2, size / 2);

    }
    const patterns = [];
    const ctx = Object.assign(document.createElement("canvas"), {width: size, height: size}).getContext("2d");
    grid(color1, color2)
    patterns[0] =  ctx.createPattern(ctx.canvas, "repeat");
    grid2(color3, color4)
    patterns[1] =  ctx.createPattern(ctx.canvas, "repeat");
    return patterns;
}


function drawGrid(ctx, grid,  zoom, origin, smooth = true) {
    function zoomAlpha(logScale) {
        const t = logScale % 3;
        return  t < 1 ? t % 1 : t > 2 ? 1 - (t - 2) % 1 : 1;
    }
    function fillScale(scale) {
        ctx.setTransform(scale / 8, 0, 0, scale / 8, origin.x, origin.y);
        ctx.globalAlpha = zoomAlpha(Math.log2(scale));
        ctx.fill();
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = grid;
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = smooth;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);    
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    const l2 = Math.log2(zoom);
    
    scales[0] = 2 ** ((l2 + 122) % 3); //  zoom limit 1 / (2 ** 122) (well beyond number precision)
    scales[1] = 2 ** ((l2 + 123) % 3); 
    scales[2] = 2 ** ((l2 + 124) % 3);    
    scales.sort((a,b) => a - b);
    
    fillScale(scales[0]);
    fillScale(scales[1]);
    fillScale(scales[2]);
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
}

function mainLoop() {
    if (innerWidth !== ctx.canvas.width || innerHeight !== ctx.canvas.height) {
        origin.x = (ctx.canvas.width = innerWidth) / 2;
        origin.y = (ctx.canvas.height = innerHeight) / 2;
        zoomTarget = 16;
        zoom = 1;
    }
    zoomC += (zoomTarget - zoom) * 0.3;    
    zoomC *= 0.02;
    zoom += zoomC;
    if (gridType === 0) {
        drawGrid(ctx, grids[0], zoom, origin);
    } else {
        drawGrid(ctx, grids[1], zoom, origin, false);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
zoomIn.addEventListener("click", () => zoomTarget *= 2);
zoomOut.addEventListener("click", () => zoomTarget *= 1/2);
toggle.addEventListener("click", () => gridType = (gridType + 1) % 2);
```

```css
* { margin: 0px;}
canvas { position: absolute; top: 0px;left: 0px; }
.UI { position: absolute; top: 14px; left: 14px; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<div class="UI">
<button id="zoomIn">Zoom In</button><button id="zoomOut">Zoom Out</button><button id="toggle">Toggle grid type</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds promising! I'll try this one